# ¿Cómo paginar en laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo la siguiente consulta y la quiero paginar mandando los resultados en una tabla que esta en la vista pero utilizo el **->paginate(3)** y me marca error. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

```
$clientes1 = clientes::orderby('razonSocial','asc')->get();
              $consulta = \DB::select("SELECT v.idServicios,v.estatusEntrega, v.estatusPago, v.estatusPortal, v.cashFlow,v.archivoRemision, v.archivo,v.archivoFactura,v.archivoPago,v.xmlFactura, v.numeroFactura,v.idFactura,v.activo,DATE_FORMAT(v.fechaFactura,'%d %b %Y') AS fecha, DATE_FORMAT(v.fechaPago,'%d %b %Y') AS fechap, v.montoFactura,
                  s.sucursal As suc, c.razonSocial AS cli FROM facturas AS v
                  INNER JOIN  sucursales as s ON s.idSucursal = v.idSucursal
                  INNER JOIN clientes AS c ON c.idc= v.idc");
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Call to a member function paginate() on array"

Comment: Necesitarás que tu consulta retorne entonces una colección y no un array como ahorita, puedes usar el query builder o las relaciones de Eloquent

Comment: Tendras algun ejemplo de como aplicarlo

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un fragmento de código que realice con Laravel 8.x Vuetify:

productoController:

```
$productos = Producto::Paginate(12);
return view('productos.index',['productos'=>$productos]);
```

index.blade:

```
    <div class="text-center">
                <v-btn href="{{$productos->previousPageUrl()}}" ><v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon></v-btn>
                @for ($i = 0; $i < $productos->lastPage(); ++$i)
                    <v-btn href="{{$productos->url($i+1)}}" >{{$i+1}}</v-btn>
                @endfor
                <v-btn href="{{$productos->nextPageUrl()}}"><v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon></v-btn>
  </div>
```

creo que puedes cambiar las `<v-btn>` por `<button>` así puedes re-usar el código.
en el enlace puede ver la documentación de mismo.
[Laravel Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)